# HTML form submit and redirect simultaneously

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have a form on my website that was not written by me and the person who did it wasn't very good (or reachable for that matter) so now by bosses want me to fix it. Currently the form on submit sends an emal and opens up a thank you message. Unfortunately that pop-up looks much more like an error message than a success message, so I was asked to redirect the submit button to an actually thank you page instead of a pop-up. Now I'm not very vast with PHP so I need some help.

HTML:

```
    <form>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="six columns">
    <label class="gfield_label" for="Name" style="display: block;">Name<span class="gfield_required">*</span></label>
      <input type="text" id="Name" required class="mobile-four"/>
      </div>
      <div class="six columns">
    <label class="gfield_label" for="Company" style="display: block;">Company</label>
      <input type="text" id="Company" required class="mobile-four"/>
      </div>
      </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="six columns mobile-four">
    <label class="gfield_label" for="email" style="display: block;">Email<span class="gfield_required">*</span></label>
      <input type="email" class="mobile-four" id="email" required  />
      </div>
      <div class="six columns mobile-four">
    <label class="gfield_label" for="phone" style="display: block;">Phone<span class="gfield_required">*</span></label>
      <input type="phone" class="mobile-four" id="phone" required  />
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
      <div class="twelve columns mobile-four">
    <label class="gfield_label" for="message" style="display: block;">Message<span class="gfield_required">*</span></label>
        <textarea id="message" cols="30" rows="3"></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="three columns centered">
          <button id="contact-submit-btn" class="btn btn-block btn-danger">Contact us Now!</button>
        </div>
        </div>
  </form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
if($_POST){
  $mailBody = "Name:" . $_POST['Name'] . "\nPhone:" . $_POST['phone'] . "\nEmail:" . $_POST['email'] . "\nMessage:\n" . $_POST['message'];
  mail("a@harbordev.com","Website request from " . $_POST['Name'], $mailBody);
}
header("location:/thankyou.html");
?>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#contact-submit-btn").click(function() {
                var form_data = {
                        Name:$("#Name").val(),
                          Company:$("#Company").val(),
                          phone:$("#phone").val(),
                        email:$("#email").val(),
                        message:$("#message").val(),
                        is_ajax: 1
                };
                $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "/contactsubmit.php",
                        data: form_data,
                        cache: false,
                        success: function(result){
                alert(result);
                        }
                });//ajax
                return false;
        });
});
```

I would like the submit button to redirect to "contact-thanks.html", which isn't written in PHP. (thankyou.html is written in PHP, but all it contains is the tank you text).

Thanks for the help

Comment: you should use document.location in your javascript after success

Comment: you should be able to simply remove the javascript and add an `action="thephpfile.php"` to the `<form>`

Comment: The header() redirect is pointless, since you're using an ajax call - all you'd be doing is redirecting the ajax call, and that's invisible in the background. You'd nee to return a success message to the page, then have the JS code do the redirect.

Comment: @MarcB It has some use if you skip the AJAX and have the form point to it, like what Kevin mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this in the success handler would do:

```
window.location = '/thankyou.html';
```

Comment: I'm sorry I have to ask this: what is the success handler?

Comment: @LauraSchoebel `success: function(result){` is where it starts

Comment: like this? success: function(result){window.location ='/contact-thanks.html'

Comment: do I need to chnage anything in the contactsubmit.php?